# Invalid identifier value or configuration

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I have 2 entities like the following :

**Campaign** :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CampaignRepository::class)
 * @ApiResource()
 */
class Campaign
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="uuid", unique=true)
     */
    private $uuid;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=AdUnit::class, mappedBy="campaign", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $adUnit;
}
```

**AdUnit** :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(schema="ad_unit")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=AdUnitRepository::class)
 * @ApiResource(
 *     attributes = {
 *         "route_prefix"="/campaigns"
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "get", "put", "patch", "delete",
 *         "get_results"={
 *             "method"="GET",
 *             "path"="/ad_unit/{campaign}/results",
 *             "controller"=AdUnitResults::class,
 *         }
 *     }
 * )
 */
class AdUnit
{
    /**
     * @ApiProperty(identifier=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ApiProperty(identifier=true)
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=Campaign::class, inversedBy="adUnit", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="campaign_uuid", referencedColumnName="uuid", nullable=false)
     */
    private $campaign;
}
```

Api identifier of **AdUnit** is set to be it's related **Campaign** `uuid` column

Whenever I try to retrieve all AdUnits on collectionOperation, I get an "Invalid identifier value or configuration" error

But itemOperations routes are all working when a "campaign.uuid" is provided